# Prevent to automatically render youtube links in Wordpress Comments

Tags: wordpress, video, comments

Wordpress is now replacing the youtube links that people post into comments of a post with the actual video.  It is rather anoying and I would like to know if it is possible to leave the link as is and not add the embed code to view the video directly from the comment container?

Comment: This is nothing to do with embedded programming, retagged.  Please read the tag description before mis-tagging. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded/info

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried entering that code in the TEXT tab rather than the VISUAL tab of the editor?